# How to validate a string input in python using datetime library and keep prompting user for input until valid input?

Tags: python, datetime, datetime-format, python-datetime

I have tried using this procedure:

```
import datetime
date_string = input()
format = "%Y-%m-%d"

try:
    datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, format)
    print("This is the correct date string format.")
except ValueError:
    print("This is the incorrect date string format. It should be YYYY-MM-DD")
```

When I fill the input of the date_string with "2021-3-3" the output is

```
This is the correct date string format.
```

But when I do a little change to "2021-03-03" the output is

```
This is the incorrect date string format. It should be YYYY-MM-DD
```

How I make the second input to be true. So, when I input "2021-03-03" the output will also be

```
This is the correct date string format.
```

I also wanna know how to prompt the user until he input the right format, so that when he input the wrong format or value, the output is

```
This is the incorrect date string format, try again fill the
```

**And, the program keep prompting user for input**

Comment: Is this the full code? Works on my machine just as intended

Comment: Yeah, it's the full code, but when I input "2021-03-03" the output is "This is the incorrect date string format. It should be YYYY-MM-DD"

Comment: print out the exception, it probably contains info that would help you debug

Comment: This code works for me, even with the 2021-03-03 input.  What version of Python are you using?

Comment: @Noah , owh, that's my bad, i input the wrong date, when I try again input 2021-03-03 it return true input statement

Comment: And, how about to keep prompting user until he gives valid input?, in this case true date format and date is really exist (there can't be 2021-02-34)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code works on my machine, and it prompts the user to input again if it doesn't succeed.

```
import datetime
format = "%Y-%m-%d"

while(True):
    date_string = input("> ").strip()
    try:
        datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, format)
        print("This is the correct date string format.")
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("This is the incorrect date string format. It should be YYYY-MM-DD")
```